# issue with CSS media queries(scrollbar)

Tags: html, css, browser

I am having problem with css media query in Firefox. It works correct in Chrome like I made two DIVs and want a scrollbar. If I decrease the screen size of firefox upto 800px then both DIVs collapse and after some pixels media query works but that not happens in Chrome.

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RMvqC/2/

Comment: +1 i also facing the same issue

Comment: I would kill for a media query like `@media all and (max-width: calc(980px + scrollbar-width))`

Comment: modern solution using media queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531872/176140

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox & Webkit based browsers render the scrollbar differently. In Firefox, MediaQuery considered width of scrollbar which is 15px with the screen width, but in Webkit based browsers it's not considered scrollbar with the screen width. So, that's why the floated DIVs are collapsed in Firefox.

I did some stuff with css may be that's help you. (check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RMvqC/5/))

```
        html {
            /* force scrollbars */
            height: 101%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0; 
            padding:0; 
            white-space:nowrap; 
        }  
        #box1,
        #box2 {
            display:inline-block;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;  
            vertical-align:top;
            white-space:normal;
        }
        #box1 {
            background: #ce0000;
             margin-right:-5px;
        }
        #box2 {
            background: #8e0000;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 799px) { 
            body { 
                white-space:normal; 
            }
            #box1,
            #box2 {
                width: 300px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Such a pain, this is why I hate front end sometimes/most of the time

Comment: This has since changed around Chrome 29 I think. The scrollbar is now included in the width of the page with respect to media query calculation

Comment: It's a shame that it's 2020 and this is still an issue. Makes media queries kind of useless for fine-tuned stuff without hacky javascript.

Comment: It's 2021 and it looks like media queries on webkit based browsers have started to consider the width of the scrollbar. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @N3R4ZZuRR0 It seems that way, but not the case with Safari 14, right?

Answer (score 16):

I SOLVED this issue by calling the "mqGenie" javascript in the head of my project.

Now the widths of my media queries work fine ( with the same value ) on  Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE  with or without scroolbars.

This javascript Adjusts CSS media queries in browsers that include the scrollbar width in the viewport width so they fire at the intended size.

You can download it from this url:

http://stowball.github.io/mqGenie/

Comment: This appears to be the real solution as much as I loathe adding MORE javascript to my project to just accommodate faulty browser behavior. Atleast it's very lightweight clocking in under 1.2KB. I might actually embed this source right into my page instead.

Comment: I feel dirty for using this, but it seems to be the only way to solve my problem.

Comment: This does exactly what media queries should already do. Thank you for solving a hugely frustrating bug.

Answer (score 7):

Firefox & Opera follows W3C spec which is to include scrollbar width in media queries width (the reason might be to avoid infinite loop as described in [a comment here](http://iamkeir.com/post/26647025450/firefox-media-query-breakpoints-wtf)), while Webkit does not (possibly coz they think it makes no sense)

There is a workaround (I've only tested this on FF), apparently if you force scrollbar to be visible all the time, then the width will now be consistent with Webkit. Here's the code:

```css
html
{
   overflow:hidden;
   height:100%;
}
body
{
   position:relative;
   overflow-y:scroll;
   height:100%;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; /* So iOS Safari gets the inertia & rubber-band effect */
}
```

If you want to apply this to FF & Opera only, you can resort to CSS hacks:

```css
/* Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix()
{
    html
    {
        overflow:hidden;
        height:100%;
    }
    body
    {
        position:relative;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:100%;
        /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;*/
    }
}

/* Opera */
x:-o-prefocus, html
{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}
x:-o-prefocus, body
{
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
}
```

It goes without saying, the caveat is the scrollbar will be visible at all times, which might be an okay compromise.

Answer (score 1):

This is peripherally related, but I found a way to detect which media-query the browser is actually using at any given moment, without having to muck around with scrollbar and body widths...

Basically, define a an absolutely positioned 1-x-1-pixel-sized list somewhere in your body, with a list-item for each media-query condition you want to be "watchable".

Then in each media-query definition, show/hide the corresponding list-item, and then simply check whether that item is visible from within your script.

Example:

```
<body>
    ...
    <ul id="mediaQueryHelper">
        <li id="desktop"></li>
    </ul>
</body>

<style type="text/less">
    #mediaQueryHelper {
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        width: 1px;
        visibility: hidden;
        top: -999px;
        left: -999px;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 481px)
    {
       #desktop { display: inline; }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)
    {
       #desktop{ display: none; }
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var _desktop = $("#desktop");

        $(window).resize(function() {
            console.log("media-query mode: " + _desktop.is(":visible") ? "DESKTOP" : "MOBILE");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Play safe!

My final strategy is added 20px to the media queries and that is my default white space on the layout.

With one exception: `@media (min-width: 320px)` At that size a don't leave the 20px white space and include one more rule to solve minor background issues:

```
html body {
    min-width: 320px;
   }
```

*20px is the scroll bar default width size.*

FYI: https://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a solution for Firefox pretty easily by using a CSS-hack. After wrapping your content in an extra `<div>` add this lines to your CSS:

```
/* Firefox-Hack */
body,  x:-moz-any-link {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#wrapper,  x:-moz-any-link {
    margin: 0 -7.5px;
}
```

Check the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agihud/1/) (jsfiddle is down right now)

To have richer responsive experience you could add another media query: [another jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agihud/3/)

The CSS-hack was found at [paulirish.com](http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/)

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

If you do not want to display the scrollbar all the time, wrap your content into `<div>` elements etc. you can use JavaScript to add a certain value to all media queries when the scrollbar is shown.

```js
// check whether scrollbar is visible
var isScrollbarVisible = window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth;

// search for media rule
var mediaRule = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];

// update media rule
mediaRule.media.mediaText = '..'
```

### Long Answer

I wrote a small script which you can include on your page. It detects when the window is resized and changes all media queries if needed. The value of the css variable `--replace-media-scrollbar` is used as the width of the scrollbar or `15px` if no value was found. This works for the media queries `with`, `min-width`, `max-width`, `height`, `min-height` and `max-height` even when they are connected using `and`.

**JavaScript:**

```js
function* visitCssRule(cssRule) {
    // visit imported stylesheet
    if (cssRule.type == cssRule.IMPORT_RULE)
        yield* visitStyleSheet(cssRule.styleSheet);

    // yield media rule
    if (cssRule.type == cssRule.MEDIA_RULE)
        yield cssRule;
}

function* visitStyleSheet(styleSheet) {
    try {
        // visit every rule in the stylesheet
        var cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
        for (var i = 0, cssRule; cssRule = cssRules[i]; i++)
            yield* visitCssRule(cssRule);
    } catch (ignored) {}
}

function* findAllMediaRules() {
    // visit all stylesheets
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0, styleSheet; styleSheet = styleSheets[i]; i++)
        yield* visitStyleSheet(styleSheet);
}

// collect all media rules
const mediaRules = Array.from(findAllMediaRules());

// read scrollbar width
var style = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
var scrollbar = style.getPropertyValue('--replace-media-scrollbar') || '15px';

// update media rules
if (scrollbar != '0px') {
    var oldValue = '0px';
    function updateMediaRulesScrollbar() {
        var newValue = window.innerWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth ? scrollbar : '0px';
        // if value changed
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
            for (var i = 0, mediaRule; mediaRule = mediaRules[i]; i++) {
                var regex = RegExp('\\((width|min-width|max-width|height|min-height|max-height): (calc\\([^)]*\\)|[^)]*)\\)', 'g');
                var replacement = '($1: calc($2 - ' + oldValue + ' + ' + newValue + '))';
                mediaRule.media.mediaText = mediaRule.media.mediaText.replace(regex, replacement);
                console.log(mediaRule);
            }
        }
        oldValue = newValue;
    }
    updateMediaRulesScrollbar();
    window.onresize = updateMediaRulesScrollbar;
}
```

**Optional CSS:**

```css
:root {
  --replace-media-scrollbar: 15px;
}
```