# Bootstrap: do media queries work differently for Firefox, opera and IE9?

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, media-queries, opera

When the media query is set for a max-width of 767px, Chrome, Safari and IE10 seem to obey the rule, but the changes are applied at 750px for Firefox, Opera and IE9.

Has anybody else experienced the same issue? Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: when using media queries, Firefox & co includes the vertical scroll bar as part of the viewport width

see here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146874/issue-with-css-media-queriesscrollbar

Comment: Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction.:)