# Media queries working at wrong browser size

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query, `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)`. When testing in Google Chrome, the browser is applying it at 448px instead of 480px. What is causing this pixel difference, and how can it be fixed?

Meta tags being used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: How are you measuring 448px?

Comment: That's the size the chrome browser states. Located in the top or bottom right.

Comment: Top or bottom right of what? Try checking `innerWidth` in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Have a chrome browser window sizer app installed

Comment: Try checking `innerWidth` in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Try *reading* it in your JavaScript *console*. Ctrl+Shift+J (or Command+Option+J).

Comment: console is detecting nothing

Comment: In your console, type “innerWidth” and press Enter. A number should appear. This is the accurate width of your content area as seen by both CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: your magic is from a far away land. Thank you for your help

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146874/issue-with-css-media-queriesscrollbar